# How can I make my Android fragment's arguments null when first navigated to?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm following the Google [code lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-fragments-navigation-component#7) for navgation using the Android Jetpack navigation component. It instructs how to navigate from Fragment A to B. However, my app needs a fragment that can navigate to itself, ie A to A again. So far this seems as I would expect: I drag a destination from the fragment to itself on the nav graph.

I can see it working when I run the app. I navigate to the fragment and use the back stack successfully.

I need to pass in a list to the fragment every time it is navigated to using arguments, like so:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.let {
            val test = it.getString("arg1").toString()
        }
    }
```

This works fine for every time I navigate to the fragment from the fragment itself (which is a recyclerView with a list of items). But for the first use of the fragment, at the top level of navigation, I want arguments to be null like the tutorial says they should be. But instead I'm getting an empty Bundle[{}].

I appreciate that this is a trivial issue, but I couldn't find anything about it online, only the opposite (ie people kept getting null args). So I thought my question would shed light on expected behaviour.

Why isn't arguments null the first time around?

**Edit:** My NavGraph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.org.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_self"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim" >
        </action>
        <argument
            android:name="argument"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Can u share your nav graph?

Comment: See edit. Thanks Arpit 

Comment: Aren't you using navArgs to receive the arguments?

Comment: I believe so according to the tutorial. Certainly when I navigate to the second level of the fragment, I received my arguments correctly. I must have made a mistake some where.